# VBA Possible loop in FOR cycle

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have an Excel file with some Pivot Tables which has a macro that opens up an Excel SOURCE file, update different Pivot Tables and lastly it should close the source file. If I comment the FOR cycle it opens and closes the SOURCE file correctly, so I suspect there is a problem in the cycle.

Thank you for any suggestion

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call aggiorna
End Sub

Sub aggiorna()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wrb As Workbook
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    
    ' Apre in sola lettura
    Set wrb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Saila\Desktop\Ore Operatori_2018.xlsx", True, True)
    
    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next pt
        
    ' Chiude Sorgente
    wrb.Close
    Set wrb = Nothing
    
ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `set wrb = ...`  then `src.Close` ... What is `src` exactly?

Comment: Specify workbook and worksheet here `ActiveSheet.PivotTables` instead of using `ActiveSheet` which is not very reliable. Instead use something like `wrb.Worksheets("SheetName").PivotTables` or if sheet names are unknown something like `wrb.Worksheets(1).PivotTables`

Comment: it was an error from a previus file, I've corrected the code. I've tried your solution changing the code, but the result is the same, it updates the Pivot but doesn't close the file.

Comment: maybe it's an issue of how much time it takes to refresh pivot tables: try adding `DoEvents` after `pt.RefreshTable`.

Comment: also , you may try removing `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` and see if code fails while in `For ... Next` loop

Comment: your error handing has the issue that it is silent. If an error occurs you will never notice. I recommend to raise the error after `ErrHandler:` if there is one. You can easily check it by `If Err.Number >0 Then` so the user at least knows that something odd happened. Otherwise you don't even notice it and you think everything went good.

Comment: @DisplayName, commenting `OnError` it gives me a "Run-time error '1004': Reference is not valid", and it highlight the line `pt.RefreshTable`

Comment: then there's some problem with that pivot table: check if it can be refreshed or whatnot (I'm not neither a user nor a fan of pivot tables)

Comment: The Pivot refers to a large table and it takes 5/6 sec to refresh. Nevertheless the Pivot is refreshed also when the error occurs (commenting `OnError`), the only visible problem is the source file not being closed.

Comment: @zeitan It's just a guess but you can try to turn of BackgroundQuery `pt.PivotCache.BackgroundQuery = False` before you `pt.RefreshTable` and turn it on after refresh. Probably the refresh is done in background and then the workbook cannot close while the refresh is still running. • Also test if there are any filters (autofilter) applied to your pivot. If so remove them before refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

most probably the code is raising some error during pivot table cycling and then it jumps to `ErrHandler:` label thus skipping both `wrb.Close` and `Set wrb = Nothing`

move these latter statements after `ErrHandler:` label

```
Sub aggiorna()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wrb As Workbook
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    ' Apre in sola lettura
    Set wrb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Saila\Desktop\Ore Operatori_2018.xlsx", True, True)

    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next pt


ErrHandler:
    ' Chiude Sorgente
    wrb.Close
    Set wrb = Nothing

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

BTW you may want to comment `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` and see where and why code fails and then enhance your code to manage the error appropriately